# UITableViewCell inside UICollectionView not selectable

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a `UIViewCollectionView`. The Cells for the collection are all clickable. Each cell contains a `UITableView` and I also want the cells of that table view to be selectable but they arent.

I set `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on the `UICollectionView`,  `UICollectionViewCell`, `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell` but I cant get the clicking working on the table view cells.

How can I do it?

In general I want all user inputs on the table view to have priority.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but it did not work because I used xib files instead of storyboard. I switched to storyboard and everything works fine.